# target an input field in ninja forms using focus and jquery

Tags: forms, input

I have been unsuccessfully trying to interact and manipulate ninja forms (wordpress form plugin).
My ultimate aim is to animate the form labels when an input field is selected, however I've stripped back the JS to something simple to try and get a reaction at all.

```
$(".nf-field-element input").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
})
```

It just gets ignored.
I even tried this (which worked for a could of manually inserted (non ninja) inputs, so I know the JS is good.

```
    $("input").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
```

Is Ninja somehow overiding?

Sorry I don't really have a fiddle or anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you need to wait for ninja form to be ready first, after you can target the input.

https://ninjaforms.com/blog/event-tracking-for-ninja-forms-no-plugin/

```
$(document).on('nfFormReady', () => {

  $(".nf-field-element input").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
   })
)}
```